# SSRS pecentage adds additional two zeroes

Tags: reporting-services

I am having a problem in formatting percentage in SSRS. I am getting -40 from my stored procedure and it displays correct when I am not applying percentage format to it. But when I applied percentage format, it adds additional 2 zeroes before the decimal point.

[image: Without formatting]

[image: With formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting a number to percentage multiplies the number by 100 and adds the % symbol next to it.

Since your procedure already returns a percentage, divide the number by 100 in order to format it as a percentage

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks for taking time to answer my question.